# Is it ok to use initWithFrame for custom tableviewcell after iPhone SDK 3.0?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

It is shown that initWithFrame is deprecated with initWithStyle in sdk3.0 and above.

But we can still use it without any warning/error. So is it ok to continue using initWithFrame for implementing custom cell in tableview?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, in principle, ok. But it doesn't really make sense for new code to do this. The frame you pass to `initWithFrame` doesn't really influence the cell anyway, which means you should just call `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, which has the same result as `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`.

In existing code, it is of course ok for some time to keep using `initWithFrame`, but when you get the chance, you should change it to `initWithStyle`. At some (unknown) point in the future, Apple will stop supporting the deprecated method, and your app won't build with new iPhone OS releases if it uses old methods.

Comment: ya I got it, in this way we can also do the same as we have to change in tableviewcell's init function also.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a few more OS releases it is OK.  Like many deprecated methods and those in the Mac OS X sdk, it takes Apple some time (years?) to actually stop supporting them.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. it seems they have deprecated but still not leave off support for old one, but they may do that after some release.
Thank You.