# Custom TableViewCell is not called (programmatically)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, custom-component

I´ve been searching a long time through a lot of code here but nothing helped me....

I created a custom TableViewCell programatically and i want to connect them with another view. Here is my Code.

The .h File

```
//  GTCustomCellView.h
#import "GTView.h"
@interface GTCustomCellView : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTView* containerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTImageView* commentImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTTextView* commentView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTTextView* dateView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTTextView* authorView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTView* groupView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* mainView;

@end
```

The .m File

```
@implementation GTCustomCellView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.layout = [[[GTFlowLayout alloc] initWithSpacing: 0] autorelease];
    self.backgroundColor = GTDefaultBackgroundColor;


    self.containerView = [[[GTView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, 100.0f)]autorelease];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.containerView];


    self.commentImageView = [[[GTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f)] autorelease];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.commentImageView];


    self.groupView =[[[GTView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width - self.commentImageView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height)]autorelease];
    [self.containerView addSubview: self.groupView];


    self.authorView = [[[GTTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, 20.0f)]autorelease];
    [self.groupView addSubview:self.authorView];

    self.dateView = [[[GTTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.frame.size.width, 20.0f)]autorelease];
    [self.groupView addSubview:self.dateView];

    self.commentView = [[[GTTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 40.0, self.frame.size.width, 60.0f)]autorelease];
    [self.groupView addSubview:self.commentView];


}
return self;
}
```

And here is the important part of the other View:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

GTCustomCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[GTCustomCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


cell.authorView.text = @"Author Test";
cell.dateView.text = @"Date Test";
cell.commentView.text = @"Comment test";


return cell;
}
```

I only get empty Cells, my only Idea is that i use Views and not UILabels?

Comment: If you call `initWithStyle` to create the cells in the table view controller, then you should implement *that*  method in the cell class, and not `initWithFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier instead of initWithFrame

additional information here:[Is it ok to use initWithFrame for custom tableviewcell after iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485747/is-it-ok-to-use-initwithframe-for-custom-tableviewcell-after-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate and the data source of the table view:

```
yourTableView.delegate = self;
yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

You should do this in your view controller.